# Add a day to departure javascript

Tags: javascript, date, calendar

Please take a look at the following javascript code:

```
// Default calendar namespaces
    var dateFormat = "<span class='day'>d</span> <span class='month'>M</span> <span class='year'>yy</span>",
        dateArrival = '#dateArrival input',
        dateDeparture = '#dateDeparture input',
        dateArrivalVal = '#dateArrival .date-value',
        dateDepartureVal = '#dateDeparture .date-value';

    // Show arrival calendar
    $(dateArrival).datepicker({
        minDate: 'D',
        dateFormat: dateFormat,
        // get value on selected date for departure
        onSelect: function (txt, inst) {
            $(dateDepartureVal).html(txt);
            $(dateArrivalVal).html($(dateArrival).val());
        },
        onClose: function (selectedDate) {
            $(dateDeparture).datepicker("option", "minDate", selectedDate);
        }
    });

    // Show departure calendar
    $(dateDeparture).datepicker({
        minDate: 'D+1',
        dateFormat: dateFormat,
        // get value on selected date for return
        onSelect: function (txt, inst) {
            $(dateDepartureVal).html(txt);
            $(dateDepartureVal).html($(dateDeparture).val());
        }
    });

    // set current date
    $('.datepicker').datepicker('setDate', 'today');
    // get current value from departure 
    $(dateArrivalVal).html($(dateArrival).val());
    // get current value from return
    $(dateDepartureVal).html($(dateDeparture).val());
```

As you can see, it is a booking widget that displays the current day as check in and the following day as check out. However, when the client chooses another day for check in, check out is set to THAT SAME day. What I want to do is, if dateArrival is chosen as, say, June 7th, dateDeparture automatically displays June 8th (that is, dateArrival + 1 day), instead of displaying the same date (June 7th). How can one do this?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Are you sure you want to do this? People sometimes fill in forms irrationally and  set their departure date before setting their arrival date and having something which changes a date they may have entered is not necessarily a good idea. You should only auto change the date if the existing one is before the arrival date

Comment: I completely understand what you mean, @vogomatix. Is there a way to only change the departure date when arrival date is set first?

Comment: @RobG: `#dateArrival input` selects all inputs inside `#dateArrival`, e.g. `#dateArrival` may be a `div` enclosing multiple `input` elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could:

1. register a change event on arrival date, which sets departure at D+1 check [jQuery .change()](https://api.jquery.com/change/)
2. register a change event on departure date, which removes previous handler, [jQuery .off](https://api.jquery.com/off/)

But the trick here is that no method from datepicker helps you to set +1 day to an arbitrary date, therefore you have to **manipulate directly your formatted string**.
I added 3 lines to produce the +1 day string, and a fourth wich uses the datepicker method to set dateDeparture. It´s tested so check if it does the job  for you

```
// Show arrival calendar
$(dateArrival).datepicker({
    minDate: 'D',
    dateFormat: dateFormat,
    // get value on selected date for departure
    onSelect: function (txt, inst) {
        $(dateDepartureVal).html(txt);
        $(dateArrivalVal).html($(dateArrival).val());
        // ADDED THESE FIVE LINES
        var d = new Date((+inst.currentMonth+1) + '/' + inst.currentDay + '/' + inst.currentYear)
        var dpo = new Date(d.getTime() + 24*60*60*1000)
        var str = "<span class=day>"+dpo.getDate()+"</span> <span class=month>"+(dpo.toDateString().split(' ')[1])+"</span> <span class=year>"+dpo.getFullYear()+"</span>"
        $(dateDeparture).datepicker('setDate', str);
        $(dateDepartureVal).html(str);
    }
    // REMOVED USELESS ONCLOSE, SINCE UI IS CLOSED ON SELECT
});
```

Comment: Could you specify with a sample code? I don't know much about javascript. Thank you!

Comment: Thank you, @lucchi. For some reason, the code won't work (when another date of arrival is set, the date of departure is set to that same day, not the day after – which is what I want to do. Forget the "if" part, it's not important if the dateDeparture was already set before). If you want, check proyectohales.com/catedral. Can you spot the reason why? Thanks!

Comment: @Alex Actually, when you select a check out date, then open the check in calender it is preset to D+1, which is the oposite of what you wanted, also this date has not been passed to .date-value. Let´s just fix this in an edit.

Comment: Thank you! This works perfectly. Only one suggestion: the onclose is not useless because it prevents the user from choosing dates previous to arrival. But thanks for the code!

Comment: @Alex, as a suggestion, you should really learn about User experience, and design automatisms that serves your users, not your needs to validate their data. And definitely not to prevent them putting a valid input somewhere, just beacuse they did put another valid input somewhere else. Now that you don´t need more code for your UI, just think a little your UX.